# Are research-related cross posts discouraged?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57957/designer-looking-for-help-with-an-algorithm-to-calculate-layout-of-rectangles-bas) was posted on math.stackexchange.com and I've become curious.  I unfortunately posted an answer that I'm disappointed with.  I've got some questions myself, and I'm wondering about the potential for relaying research-level information from this site to another site.

In other words, I'd like to know if it's discouraged for me to ask a question here inspired by a question from another site (while that question hasn't been answered)?  I'd like to research the information using this site and the web and eventually post an answer that's not so research level on the other site, math.stackexchange.

I'm wondering what I should do here - I really feel I've made a mistake already.

Comment: related: [site policy on cross-posting](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/231#231)

Answer (score 10):

If you can restate the question as a research-level tiling or packing question, then I think people will be happy to answer it here. Taking an ambiguous and open-ended application question and reformulating it as a legitimate TCS problem is often non-trivial, and thus I don't think that your question would count as cross-posting.

If you get good answers on cstheory, then you can link the original OP here, or if you syntehsize many answers into one more accessible answer that is relevant to the math OP then you can probably post it as your answer with links back to cstheory.

However, just taking an arbitrary question from math.SE and cross-posting it to cstheory.SE is discouraged unless it is clear that cstheory is a better scope for the question (i.e. if the question is clearly a research-level TCS problem) in which case you should consider flagging it for migration.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with Artem.  Just to add, please do not forget to link to the original question which inspired you.  A link is useful for curious readers, and also I think that this is a proper way to give a credit to the original asker.  As for the other direction, I think that it is better to post a link to your question as a comment to the original question even before you get an answer.